# Attaching tabindex to headings

Tags: html

I am currently working on the accesibility of my website, specially for blind people who navigate with screen readers.

I did manage to remove the anchors that should be skipped when navigating with tab by just using tabindex, but I'd like the screen reader software to read a custom text whenever the user navigates to an h1/h2/h3.. tag.

I did try attaching tabindex="1" to the heading tag but It didnt work out.

This is an example of the problem im facing:

### List of our services

- Web design
- Graphic design
- Branding

In this current example, the list items are properly read by the screen reader software when navigating with tab because they are anchor tags, but it dodges the "list of our services" heading.

Is there any kind of "alt" attribute that can be attached to headings in order to fix this? If not possible, i'll just add a transparent 1 pixel image before every heading with the alt tag, like this:

```
<a href="#"><img alt="List of our services" src="/1pixelimage.jpg"></a>
<h2>List of our services</h2>
```

However, I dont think this is correct and I might be missing the real way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Screen reader users can navigating heading without the need of the `tabindex="0"`. This is a build in feature for screen readers. That is pressing the h key in form modes off. Will navigate to all heading. Pressing the number 1 will navigate to `<h1>` and 2 will navigate to `<h2>` and so on if these elements exist on a webpage

Adding the `tabindex="0"` to heading will not impove the screen reader users experience but will help keyboard users that are not able to navigate heading with the tab key to now access the headings on you page.

I would not advice adding a custome message on your heading elements `<h1> <h2>` and `<h3>`. If you want to customise the heading contect I will ask why. Would other uses also find the information provide. Providing a custome message that only screen reader users can see but no other users can cause more harm than good as it could confuse screen reader users who can see. Examples would be

1. People with low vision
2. People with cognitive disability
3. People with other reading disabilities

that use screen readers to help them read the content on a webpage page.

Answer (score 1):

I was messing up with tabindex value and missing title attribute on headings.

This heading is navigable with tab hotkeys and reproduces audio title for screen readers:

```
<h2 tabindex="0" title="List of our services">List of our services</h2>
```